# What is a "decade" as a unit of measure (ex. a decade of the EM spectrum)?

Tags: electromagnetism, terminology, units

Reading through papers and online sources about radio galaxies, I kept stumbling across a term--a "decade" of the electromagnetic spectrum. Radio galaxy emission encompasses "11 decades of the EM spectrum". Or this quote from NASA:

> Astronomers have made observations of electromagnetic radiation from cosmic sources that cover a range of more than 21 decades in wavelength (or, equivalently in frequency or energy)!

[Source.](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/heasarc/headates/spectrum.html)

What exactly does this term correspond to?

Note: I used the [electromagnetism](/questions/tagged/electromagnetism) tag because of the context, but I am not sure if the unit can be used outside of the field. Feel free to edit away!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From 10Hz to 100Hz is a decade (on a logarithmic axis this is $10^2$ to $10^3$).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! So a decade is 10^(x) to 10^(x+1) range? When they say "11 decades" they mean that radio galaxies emit light with wavelengths from (for example, not sure if this is accurate) 10^(-1) m to 10^(10)m?

Comment: @JosephFarah yes.

Comment: Outside of  log-scaled stuff like wavelengths and frequencies, you're much more likely to encounter the phrase "order of magnitude" to describe a 10x difference.  However, it would be wrong (or at least, imprecise) to use that phrase for a log-scaled unit because an increase of 10x is "not a big deal" in that context (compared to a linear context where a 10x increase is a huge deal).

Comment: @Kevinl: What do you mean by log-scaled unit? Are you talking about graphical representation or about the units themselves?

Comment: This is a nice example, but an example is not a definition.  The answer doesn't even state that it's using a particular range as an example.  According to this answer, a decade is "From 10Hz to 100Hz" and nothing else.  Implying that the range from 100 Hz to 1000 Hz would NOT be a decade.  That's just wrong.

Comment: Ok, it isn't a formal answer. However, from my point of view, sometimes a short examples is better than a long formal definition

Comment: Examples are fine. Not explaining what in blazes you're talking about isn't. I couldn't make any sense of the example without reading the other answers.

Comment: Decade is also often used informally in cosmological time scales. E.g. We live in the 10th decade of the universe, and proton decay is speculated to occur in the 80th decade.

Comment: I encountered this term in the 1990s, and I got the impression that it was old then, because it referred to an old piece of electronic test equipment.  A *decade box* is a series of potentiometers, each a power of ten larger than the next. You can adjust the resistance through the box with great precision (thanks to the small value pots) over a very large range (thanks to the large ones). Radio astronomers may have used a similar device to tune their telescopes.

Answer (score 37):

While many units are available for physical measurables, there are only a few that identify unitless variables, like ratios.

One is 'octave', meaning a factor of two (usually in frequency); another is 'decade', meaning a factor of ten.   A third is bel, which grows
a suffix from time to time, and indicates (almost always) a factor
of ten in power.   The tenth-of-a-bel, decibel, is denoted 'dB'.

Percent, parts-per-million, pH, are also unitless.

Any attempt to line-fit data on log/log or semilog plots will 
involve one or more axes being unitless, and give rise to
phrases like 'dB per octave'.   When your data is spread
over a 100:1 range, it might look best on two-decade semilog
paper.

Comment: Ahh...semilog paper.  Great for feeding a chart recorder plugged to a transimpedance amplifier.  Now just to find those punchcards so we can analyze the data.

Comment: The kind of naming convention that makes “octave” a factor of 2, but “decade” a factor of 10, makes me cry of pain.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek of course the use of *octave* comes from music, but that doesn't make it less annoying

Comment: Yes, I know where it comes from. (By the way, I don’t want to digress too much, but the musical naming convention is broken on its own: ignoring the fact that the tones that make up the octave are of at least two different lengths, there are only *seven* of them, not eight. For reasons possibly connected with the nonexistence of zero in ancient Greece, they count both the endpoints in the tally.)

Comment: There are eight (diatonic) tones in a musical octave, not seven, @EmilJeřábek. Seven tones only gets you to the seventh scale degree, not to the octave.

Comment: @Beanluc Count with me: C=0 D=1 E=2 F=3 G=4 A=5 B=6 C=7. These are seven steps, not eight.

Comment: Seven **steps**, yes. Seven **tones**? Count again. The number of **tones**, not the number of steps, is why it's called an octave.

Comment: @RussellBorogove What I meant by suffix, is the dBm type of suffix; that one means power into a 600 ohm load, relative to (i.e. zero defined as) one milliwatt.   The other salient feature of dB is that one dB refers to the tenth root of the ratio-of-ten that is one bel.

Answer (score 20):

A decade is a factor of $10$, so it's a way of assigning a unit to the common logarithm ($\mathrm{log}_{10}$). It's also frequently assigned the unit symbol $\mathrm{dex}$.